# error in reading in File handling c++

Tags: c++

I am making a huffman tree and I have completed my work. But a problem has occured when I read a char, it reads zero instead of  space " " in the first part .

Here is the code. The error occurs in the  `decode` function  during file handling.

```
void huffmantree<h>::decode(){
    CString *st;
hscll<h> * temp=new hscll<h> ();
int h;
    ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("z://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaae.txt");
  myfile >>h;
  cout<<h;

  for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
  {char  temp9[100];
  char l;

  myfile >>l; 
  temp->insert(l);
     // myfile >> l ;

      myfile >> temp9;
      temp->atindex(i)->symboc.symbol=l;
      temp->atindex(i)->code->setString(temp9);
      //myfile >> '\n';
  }
  _getch();

    //CString u;
    //char k;
    //int p=0;
    //for(int i=0;i<st->m_length;i++)
    //{
    //  for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
    //  {
    //      
    //      char a;
    //      a=st->charAt(i);
    //      int temp=1;
    //      if(j==0)
    //          temp=1;
    //      if(a!='0')
    //      {
    //          for(int y=0;y<j;y++)
    //              {
    //                      temp*=2;
    //              }
    //          p+=temp;
    //      }
    //      else 
    //      {
    //      p+=0;
    //      
    //      }

    //      i++;
    //      cout<<a;
    //  }
    //  k=p;
    //  char t=7;
    //  //cout<<"      "<<t<<"    "<<p<<endl;
    //  myfile << k;
    //  p=0;
    //  u.addcharbychar(k);
    //}
    ////cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<u.getString();
    ////cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"the length is =="<<u.m_length<<endl;
  myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `>>` for input, leading whitespace will be skipped.  If you're reading binary data, you need to open the file in binary mode (`myfile.open( name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary`) and use the non-formatting input functions, like `istream::get()`.  (And when writing, you'll also need to write binary.)

Comment: You can have whitespace not skipped by using [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws)

Comment: You mean `std::noskipws`; `std::ws` explicitly skips spaces.  You can, but it's much more natural to use the functions designed for this type of work.

Comment: Yes, `std::noskipws`. Somehow I thought it was a binary toggle... My mistake.